# How to extract unique values from a multiple Excel worksheets?

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have two sheets: Day 1 and Day 2

Day 1:
COLUMN A
TeamName
Team 1
Team 2
Team 3

Day 2:
COLUMN A
TeamName
Team 1
Team 2
Team 9

The output will be:
Team 1
Team 2
Team 3
Team 9

My formula returns only Day 1 data:

=IFERROR(INDEX('Day 1'!$A$2:$A$4; MATCH(0; INDEX(COUNTIFS($A$1:A1;'Day 1'!$A$2:$A$4); 0; 0); 0)); "")

How to include the Day 2 too?

Comment: Does this have to be dynamic or is it a once off task?

Comment: Dynamic, but the number of teams is fixed. The team name can be changed.

Comment: Could you then just have another column on your final sheet that pull the names from the other sheets i.e. on that sheet in A2 you'd have `='Day 1'!A2` and drag down to A4 and then in A5 you'd have `Day 2!A2` and drag down to A7. So now that you've made them one concatenated list on a single sheet, your original formula will work `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$7; MATCH(0; INDEX(COUNTIFS($A$1:A1;$A$2:$A$7); 0; 0); 0)); "")`

Comment: The common algorithm goes: 1) add them all to a single array, 2) sort for unique values